# Preventing repeated package installation, or pre installing packages in R

Tags: r, docker, rpy2

I have a R script that I call from python using rpy2. It uses dplyr, doBy, and ggplot2. The script has install.packages commands for these 3 packages. Even thought the packages are already installed it still downloads,  builds, and installs them, which is very time consuming. Is there a way to have it only do the install if the package is not already installed?

Also, I run in a docker container, so after the container is instantiated the packages are not there the first time the script runs. Is there a way to pre load the packages, in which case I would not need the install.packages commands for these packages and my above question would become moot.

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile? Which image are you using and how are you installing the packages from install.packages while building the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use:

```
if (!require(package)) install.packages("package")
```

So if the package isn't available in the library, it will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages( setdiff(required_packages, installed.packages()[,"Package"]) )
```

If you define `required_packages` as a character vector of the names of the packages you need, this line will only install the packages you don't currently have.

So for your case:

```
required_packages <- c("dplyr", "doBy", "ggplot2")
install.packages( setdiff(required_packages, installed.packages()[,"Package"]) )
```